# Hibernate - Avoid the creation of a cross-table in oneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

In a `one to many`/`many to one` bidirectional relation, to avoid the creation of  a cross-table I either add `@mappedBy` to the `@ManyToMany` or I add a `@JoinColumn` annotation.

So which one is the best?

P.S: I know that `@mappedBy` is used to tell Hibernate that the other table (`many to one`) is responsible for updating the relation.

Comment: @mappedTo doesn't exist. I don't see how it would be possible to implement a ManyToMany without a join table. Is your question the question in the title? What's the relationship between the text of the question and its title?

Comment: oups I will correct it. I meant `@mappedBy` in `one to many`/`many to one` relation. And the question is in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confused. First of all, `mappedBy` is not an annotation. It's an attribute of the `@OneToOne`, `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` annotations.

Its purpose is always the same: when the association is a bidirectional association, the inverse side has to have this attribute. And there MUST be an inverse side. And in the case of a OneToMany association, the inverse side MUST be the One side.

`@JoinColumn` doesn't have much to do with `mappedBy`. It's used, on the owner side (or unique side if the association is unidirectional) of the association, to tell Hibernate that the association is materialized in database by a given join column (or foreign key if you prefer). If you don't specify JoinColumn, Hibernate will use a default mapping.

Your question is still not very clear, so I'll assume that you want to avoid the default mapping in a OneToMany unidirectional association, which consists in using a join table. Since it's a unidirectional association, mappedBy is irrelevant. But you can simply use JoinColumn to tell Hibernate that it must use a join column and not a join table:

```
public class Car
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
    private Set<Wheel> wheels;
}
```

Note that this is documented, with an example, in the [JoinColumn javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html), and in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#example.collection.mapping.annotations).

Comment: Your explanation of the `mappedBy` is very clear. It must be used in bidirectional associations. In a unidirectional association where I dont want to use a `join table`, I have to use `@JoinColumn` to avoid the default `@JoinTable`.